# Web Scraping Google scholar via selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to scrape the Citations,h-index and i10-index from google scholar page and store it in a pandas dataframe using selenium webdriver.Below is my web driver code.

```
# install chromium, its driver, and selenium
!apt-get update
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
!pip install selenium
# set options to be headless, ..
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
# open it, go to a website, and get results
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)

wd.get("https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=kukA0LcAAAAJ&hl=en&oi=ao")
divs = wd.find_elements_by_class_name('gsc_rsb'

for i in divs[0].find_elements_by_tag_name('a'):
  #print(i)
  print(i.get_attribute('text'))
```

which results in below :

```
Get my own profile
Citations
h-index
i10-index
1051
1163
1365
1762
2001
2707
4192
7293
13372
25177
40711
65915
87193
101992
21846
View all
Aaron Courville
Pascal Vincent
Kyunghyun Cho
Ian Goodfellow
Yann LeCun
Hugo Larochelle
Caglar Gulcehre
Dzmitry Bahdanau
David Warde-Farley
Xavier Glorot
Razvan Pascanu
Leon Bottou
Sherjil Ozair
Mehdi Mirza
James Bergstra
Olivier Delalleau
Anirudh Goyal
Pascal Lamblin
Patrick Haffner
Nicolas Le Roux
```

But I need only citations,h-index,i10-index like below pandas dataframe :

```
|  Name       |   Citations(All)   | Citations(since2016) | i10-index|i10-index(since2016)|
+-------------+--------------------+----------------------+----------+--------------------+
|Yoshua Bengio|   387118           |   343301             |  181     |        164         |
```

How can this be achieved through the above code ?

Answer (score 1):

In C# .Net

**Selenium** uses the Webdriver protocol to automate processes on various popular browsers such as Firefox, Chrome, and Safari. This automation can be carried out locally (for purposes such as testing a web page) or remotely (for purposes such as web scraping).

**Html Agility Pack (HAP)** is a free and open-source HTML parser written in C# to read/write DOM and supports plain XPATH or XSLT. It is a . NET code library that allows you to parse "out of the web" HTML files.

**First Load packages:-**

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;

using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

using HtmlAgilityPack;

public IWebDriver driver;
```

[Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fvlf9.png)

**Search button code:-**

```
 string selected = textBox1.Text;
 var driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
 driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
 // var options = new ChromeOptions();
 // options.AddArgument("headless");
 driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService);
 driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=" + selected + "&oq=");
```

**Scrape Button Code:-**

```
  IList<IWebElement> searchElements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath(".//div[@class='abstract-text row']"));
            foreach (IWebElement i in searchElements)
            {
                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                var text = i.GetAttribute("innerHTML");
                htmlDocument.LoadHtml(text);
                var tds = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("div");

                //  var links = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//a[@class='v-align-middle']").ToList();

                        richTextBox1.AppendText("-----------------------------\n\n\n");

                        richTextBox1.AppendText(tds.InnerText.Trim() ?? " ");
                        this.richTextBox1.Text = this.richTextBox1.Text.Trim();
                        richTextBox1.Font = new Font("Georgia", 15);
  
            }
```

**Close Button Code:-**

```
 driver.Close();
```

*`Youtube Video for Complete Implementation of code`*

[Web Scraping Of Abstract From Google Scholar Website Using Selenium Driver-Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8YAadHGWsAQ)

Answer (score 0):

```py
divs = wd.find_elements_by_class_name('gsc_rsb' #no closing bracket
```

[SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) to quickly find `CSS` selectors in combination with `select()` / `select_one()` `BeautifulSoup` methods.

Note, even with `selenium` or `requests-html` it still might throw a CAPTCHA. The first thing you can do is to add proxy to your request if custom header doesn't helped.

Here's what I come up with (*it worked for me on other profiles as well*):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=kukA0LcAAAAJ')
html = browser.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

name = soup.select_one('#gsc_prf_in').text

cititations_all = soup.select_one('tr:nth-child(1) .gsc_rsb_sc1+ .gsc_rsb_std').text
cititations_since_2016 = soup.select_one('tr:nth-child(1) .gsc_rsb_std+ .gsc_rsb_std').text

h_index_all = soup.select_one('tr:nth-child(2) .gsc_rsb_sc1+ .gsc_rsb_std').text
h_index_since_2016 = soup.select_one('tr:nth-child(2) .gsc_rsb_std+ .gsc_rsb_std').text

i_10_index_all = soup.select_one('tr~ tr+ tr .gsc_rsb_sc1+ .gsc_rsb_std').text
i_10_index_since_2016 = soup.select_one('tr~ tr+ tr .gsc_rsb_std+ .gsc_rsb_std').text

data = {
    "Name": [name],
    "Citations": cititations_all,
    "Citations Since 2016": cititations_since_2016,
    "h-index": h_index_all,
    "h-index Since 2016": h_index_since_2016,
    "i10-index": i_10_index_all,
    "i10-index Since 2016": i_10_index_since_2016,
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
            Name Citations Citations 2016 h-index h-index 2016 i10-index  \
0  Yoshua Bengio    387118         343301     181          164       625   

  i10-index 2016  
0            55
```

---

Other solution using `requests-html` - [docs](https://docs.python-requests.org/projects/requests-html/en/latest/).

Code:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import pandas as pd

session = HTMLSession()
url = 'https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=kukA0LcAAAAJ'
r = session.get(url)
r.html.render()

name = r.html.find('#gsc_prf_in', first = True).text

citations_all = r.html.find('.gsc_rsb_std', first = True).text
citations_2016 = r.html.find('#gsc_rsb_st > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(3)', first = True).text

h_index = r.html.find('#gsc_rsb_st > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2)', first = True).text
h_index_2016 = r.html.find('#gsc_rsb_st > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(3)', first = True).text

i10_index = r.html.find('#gsc_rsb_st > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2)', first = True).text
i10_index_2016 = r.html.find('#gsc_rsb_st > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(3)', first = True).text

data = {
    "Name": [name],
    "Citations": citations_all,
    "Citations 2016": citations_2016,
    "h-index": h_index,
    "h-index 2016": h_index_2016,
    "i10-index": i10_index,
    "i10-index 2016": i10_index_2016,
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

Output (I guess PyCharm doesn't like long names in the console so it replaces them with `...` but values are there):

```
            Name Citations Citations 2016  ... h-index 2016 i10-index i10-index 2016
0  Yoshua Bengio    388599         344787  ...          164       627            552
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [Google Scholar Author Cited By API](https://serpapi.com/google-scholar-author-cited-by) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free trial of 5,000 searches. Check out the [playground](https://serpapi.com/playground?engine=google_scholar_author&author_id=m8dFEawAAAAJ&hl=en) to test out.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os

params = {
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
  "engine": "google_scholar_author",
  "author_id": "9PepYk8AAAAJ",
  "hl": "en",
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

citations_all = results['cited_by']['table'][0]['citations']['all']
citations_2016 = results['cited_by']['table'][0]['citations']['since_2016']
h_inedx_all = results['cited_by']['table'][1]['h_index']['all']
h_index_2016 = results['cited_by']['table'][1]['h_index']['since_2016']
i10_index_all = results['cited_by']['table'][2]['i10_index']['all']
i10_index_2016 = results['cited_by']['table'][2]['i10_index']['since_2016']

print(f'{citations_all}\n{citations_2016}\n{h_inedx_all}\n{h_index_2016}\n{i10_index_all}\n{i10_index_2016}\n')

public_access_link = results['public_access']['link']
public_access_available_articles = results['public_access']['available']

print(f'{public_access_link}\n{public_access_available_articles}\n')

# Output:
'''
67595
28238
110
63
966
448

https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=list_mandates&hl=en&user=9PepYk8AAAAJ
7
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.

Comment: Thanks, The missing closing bracket is actually a typo from my end. 
However, when i tried running your solution in Google colab I get an error ```NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.```

Comment: That's interesting. I'm not sure what is causing this problem. I tried running the same code as I showed you, and it worked both in PyCharm and JyputerNotebook. Possibly, the environment is not fully set up, but it's just a guess. 

I added another solution in the answer above that worked for me just fine using `requests-html` library.

Comment: Unfortunately even the other solution failed with error ```RuntimeError: Cannot use HTMLSession within an existing event loop. Use AsyncHTMLSession instead.```. 
I have shared my Google colab link so that you can understand better on what is causing the problem
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ms3txbHZgfu1o8Tf9XXnRtxymT-M9jeb?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you tried running the code in local IDE?  PyCharm, VSCode, etc? I guess Google Colab already has its own event loop running. Try to add these lines of code BEFORE your script, maybe it will help: 

```import asyncio
if asyncio.get_event_loop().is_running():
    import nest_asyncio
    nest_asyncio.apply()``` 

Probably, you should install ```nest_asyncio``` before running the script with added lines above.
Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I tried the running in VSCode as advised by you, but still the AsyncHTMLSession persists.Screenshot in link :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ot4VFAaEHY7DJ4h8p_6aUL8E6rlk11qQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm not sure. I guess it's some sort of environment issue, you need to google it.

Not really helpful, but want to show you that it's working for me: https://youtu.be/1ao4OgvBDqA

Comment: Alright, will google it once.I will try in another computer. One more, sorry to ask, instead of putting the link in "browser.get" and then searching for citations can we take the names from a dataframe/csv and then extract the citations (using same) and store in a different df at end ? If so, the answer can be updated.

Comment: I'm not sure. It needs to be tested :)

Comment: alright thanks, incase you want to test it, I will edit my post accordingly, let me know :).